# Random Password with 4 characters from String

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, char

I made a code that gives me every possible 4 character combination of a String.
Now I need to make a program that chooses 1 random combination as a Password and then goes over every possible combination till it finds the chosen one and then tells me how many guesses it took to find the right one. This is what I have so far:

```
String alphabet = "ABCabc012!";
        char pw[] = alphabet.toCharArray();
        

        for (int i = 0; i < pw.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pw.length ; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < pw.length ; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < pw.length ; l++) {

                        System.out.println(pw[i] + " " + pw[j] + " " + pw[k] + " " + pw[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to store the pw[] in an array but I dont know exactly how to do it.

Comment: Your alphabet consists of 10 distinct characters. Your password is 4 characters long. 10^4 possibilities.  On average an exhaustive search will take 5000 tries.

Comment: Don't need to store anything other than one value. Just have a random break and store the value at that point. Then look for it using the code you've got

Comment: Sorry but I am completly lost, wich value and how? I'm thinking about an Array List

Comment: I realize this is likely an assignment and you're simply trying to satisfy the requirements given to you, but you don't actually need to do anything here except pick a random number between 0 and the number of possible passwords, which will give you an identical result to actually computing the whole set of passwords, picking a random one, and then counting how many guesses it takes to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to store the values in a list beforehand?
Do you need to generate each value exactly once, or it does not matter?

If you can just generate random passwords of size 4 N times, you could try something like this:

```
public class RandomPass {
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "ABCabc012!";
    String password = generatePassword(4, alphabet);
    System.out.println("PW is: " + password);

    int counter = 0;
    while (!generatePassword(4, alphabet).equals(password)) {
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("It took: " + counter + " times.");
}

private static String generatePassword(int size, String alphabet) {
    StringBuilder pw = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pw.append(alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(0, alphabet.length())));
    }
    return pw.toString();
}
```

}

If you really need to store them, so do it inside an ArrayList, instead of printing them as you are doing in your code.

After that, you can just traverse the ArrayList and search for your password in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually pretty close!

Here's how to build the combinations, add them to the ArrayList, output them, pick a random password from the list, then randomly generate passwords until you get a match:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "ABCabc012!";
    char pw[] = alphabet.toCharArray();

    // generate the combinations
    ArrayList<String> combos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pw.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pw.length ; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < pw.length ; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < pw.length ; l++) {
                  String pwCombo = "" + pw[i] + pw[j] + pw[k] + pw[l];
                  combos.add(pwCombo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // output the combinations
    for(String password : combos) {
      System.out.println(password);
    }

    // pick a random passwrod
    Random r = new Random();    
    int index = r.nextInt(combos.size());
    String pwToGuess = combos.get(index);
    System.out.println("Password to guess: " + pwToGuess);

    // randomly generate a password until it matches
    int tries = 0;
    String pwGuess = "";
    do {
      tries++;
      pwGuess = "" + pw[r.nextInt(pw.length)] + pw[r.nextInt(pw.length)] + pw[r.nextInt(pw.length)] + pw[r.nextInt(pw.length)];
    } while (!pwGuess.equals(pwToGuess));
    System.out.println("It took " + tries + " tries to guess the password!");
  }
```